# Combining field values from several rows into one group footer field

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports

My Crystal Report has the following functions, which concatenate values from several records into a single field in the group footer. It works pretty well, but now I need to change it so blank records aren't taken into account. How can I achieve this?

Group header code:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
StringVar Array reset;
StringVar Array ServiceIDs:=reset;
True;
```

Group detail code:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
StringVar Array SErviceIDs;

Redim Preserve ServiceIDs[Ubound(ServiceIDs)+1];
serviceIDs[Ubound(ServiceIDs)]:={OPERATION.SERVICE_ID};
```

Group footer code:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
StringVar Array ServiceIDs;
Join (ServiceIDs, "|");
```

The reults look like this:

> PASSIVATE|||||OUTHEAT
>
> |||
>
> || ZINC

but I'd like them to look like this:

> PASSIVATE|OUTHEAT
>
> blank
>
> ZINC

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the desired behavior by editing the code in the details section:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
StringVar Array ServiceIDs;

If Not IsNull({OPERATION.SERVICE_ID}) Then
(
    Redim Preserve ServiceIDs[Ubound(ServiceIDs) + 1];
    serviceIDs[Ubound(ServiceIDs)] := {OPERATION.SERVICE_ID};
)
```